# Printing prime numbers using while loop, not working as desired

Tags: java, while-loop

The inner while loop variable j remains at 3 after incrementating, instead it should be 1 for next iteration. Due to this, the inner while condition fails and gets terminated and output is only 2, instead of 2, 3, 5.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i=2;
    int j=1;
    int count=0;

    while(i<=5)
    {
        while(j<=i)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                count++;        
            }
            
            j++;
        }

        if(count==2)
            System.out.println(i);    
        
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: You never reset the value, so why do you think it should be 1?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Mark
No idea how to reset, could you please check and modify.

Comment: You can reset it by assigning the desired value at the right point in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the inner loop variable `j` and the `count` for each execution of the outer loop:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 2;

    while (i <= 5) {
        int j = 1;
        int count = 0;

        while (j <= i) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                count++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        if (count == 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```